# Maths Two Percentage Increases - Any Takers

Tags: math, reverse-engineering, percentage

Maths Puzzle

```
A = 10 (COST)
B = 20 (Sell Price)
C = 15% (Fee) 
D = Tax at 20% or 1/6th if you are taking it away
E = Margin


B x C = 3.60
B / 6 in Reverse = 3.33
E = B - A - (B x C) - (B  / 6) = 3.07
```

Ok The above works correct when i i provide B Sell Price

I want a formula that will Give me  E, If i say E = 3.07 It says B = 20

How would i do that, the math

Any boffins can help

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

- You did not use **D**: I suppose instead of **B / 6**, it should read **B x D**, where **D** can be either **20%** or **16,666...%**
- There is a mistake: **B x C** is not **3.60** for the given values (**B=20, C=15%**), it is **3**.

This is a matter of mathematical deduction:

Given the equation:

> **E = B - A - (B x C) - (B  x D)**

Add **A** to both sides:

> **E + A = B - (B x C) - (B x D)**

Isolate **B**:

> **E + A = B x (1 - C - D)**

Divide both sides by **(1 - C - D)**. Condition: **C + D** cannot equal **100%**

> **(E + A) / (1 - C - D) = B**

So there is your formula for calculating **B**. Take note of the condition: this only holds true when **C + D** is not equal to **100%**.